# Axios post request failure from React front end to Laravel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel, axios

i've recently started learning Laravel and all the backend Php structure. I am trying to make a simple post request from a form i made with React and i want it stored to my sql database. I've already created the model, migrate the table inside the Db. There is only one field, and is the name inserted in the input text. 
this is my code so far:
react form:

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      name: ""
    }

    this.onSubmit= this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = e =>{
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const {name} = this.state;

    let data = {
      name: name
    };






        axios.post('/', data)
            .then(response => {
               console.log(data);

            })
            .catch(err => {
               console.log(err);

            })

};

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label>name</label>
         <input type="text"  onChange={this.onChange}></input>
         <button type="submit">submit</button> 
          </form>

    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>

        </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// The frontend is an SPA, so point all URIs (except /api/*) to the AppController.
Route::get('{uri?}', 'AppController@app')->where(['uri' => '^(?!api).*$'])->name('app');






Route::post('/', 'StoreDataCOntroller@store');


?>
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Form;

class StoreDataCOntroller extends Controller
{
    public function store(){
        $data = new Form();

        $data->name = request('name');


        $data->save();
    }
}
```

The model (empty):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
    //
}
```

and the Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFormsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string("name");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('forms');
    }
}
```

my env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ZJmPVhi6byB/kzZt/IEyEBFYK3QUVc6b+65ITHDo/pM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=ciaoss
```

Now when in the react input i press submit, i will have a generic error "internal server error 500".
Where am i doing wrong?
thank you for the help :)

EDIT:
The error log information

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dev-test\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:453)
```

Comment: can you post the full output of the laravel.log error?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GRH9dYc8

Answer (score 1):

As seen in your Laravel.log, you have the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

In your Form model you need to set

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Comment: But i didn't set in the migrations any field with timestamps. I have only name field. I've started with one field just for testing

Comment: Laravel assumes every table has timestamps even if they are not in your migration. So you still need to turn them off via the code above in your model.

Comment: Thank you so much, i've added inside the migration and now it works. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default, Laravel expects timestamps (created_at and updated_at) fields to be created through migration. That leaves you with two options

1. Tell the model that there are no timestamps

   ```
   class Form extends Model
   {
       public $timestamps = false;
   }
   ```
2. Add to your migration timestamps

```
class CreateFormsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string("name");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('forms');
    }
}
```

Also, in the controller, a function should return some response.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Form;

class StoreDataCOntroller extends Controller
{
    public function store(){
        $data = new Form();

        $data->name = request('name');


        $data->save();
        return response()->created();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried but i still got the error. Here is what they says in the console.log :  ``` Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)```

Comment: You need to check the logs on the PHP level. Usually it's located at storage/logs/laravel.log Open that file and see at the bottom what error is showing.

Comment: #40 C:\\Users\\leont\\Desktop\\dev-test-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\Users\\leont\\Desktop\\dev-test-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\Users\\leont\\Desktop\\dev-test-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(1

Comment: There's definitely something there but unfortunately the full error message is cropped out. See if you can get the full error message or just use something like pastebin to share the file contents

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:https://pastebin.com/GRH9dYc8

Comment: Add public $timestamps = false in your model, sorry not at the computer right now

Comment: Thank you i will try now

Comment: i tried but that as well didn't fix the issue. For me there is something when i post the data from axios inside the route "/". I'm sure this get route is causing the trouble: // The frontend is an SPA, so point all URIs (except /api/*) to the AppController.
Route::get('{uri?}', 'AppController@app')->where(['uri' => '^(?!api).*$'])->name('app');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206245/discussion-between-chirstiana-eriksten-and-vladan).